# High Gas Fees Across Many Testnets

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, axelar

I am testing a cross-chain GMP solidity contracts on the mumbai and binance testnets but the fees are very high on both networks, couldn't get the minimum required amount from the official faucets too! Ethereum testnet(goerli) is taking too long for the confirmation.
Is there any alternative way to test my contract? I am aware of the local hardhat network or local ganache network but trying to run a transaction between multiple blockchains so don't think those are viable options for me.

Answer (score 1):

Launch local test network with [**Hardhat**](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/overview) and deploy your contracts. If your contracts need access to other on-chain third-party contracts: tokens, protocols - you can launch the node in forking mode.

```
npx hardhat node --fork RPC_NODE
```

- You can launch the node in the cloud and make it accessible from anywhere.
- You can add your test RPC node to metamask and interrogate as with the mainnet.

Comment: Thx!  However, I am trying to test cross-chain txs I think hardhat nodes will only allow for single chain transactions

Comment: You can launch forks of different chains